# NDK Static library project doesn't compile for arm64-v8a

Tags: compiler-errors, ld, ndk-build

I'm trying to build one static library (cocos2d) using android-ndk-r13b.
I have Android.mk for static library project and there is specified

```
APP_ABI := armeabi armeabi-v7a arm64-v8a
```

a list of target architectures. The problem is that arm64-v8a fails to build on last step (linking).

make produces the output below:

```
collect2: fatal error: cannot find 'ld'
  compilation terminated.
```

I don't understand, whats wrong. this utility is definetly exists. I can run it from terminal.

```
ld -v
@(#)PROGRAM:ld  PROJECT:ld64-253.3
configured to support archs: i386 x86_64 x86_64h armv6 armv7 armv7s armv7m armv7k arm64 (tvOS)
LTO support using: LLVM version 3.7.1
```

It states that arm64 is supported.
I don't understand which direction should I dig now.
`armeabi armeabi-v7a` are compiling well, I get two .so files after all.

Answer (score 0):

Ok looks like I've found a solution or rather a workaround I believe.
I took full command of ndk-build that is running by `make` and added NDK_LOG=1 flag. It gave me a clue. Linker is trying to run from
`~/Library/android/ndk/android-ndk-r13b/toolchains/aarch64-linux-android-4.9/prebuilt/darwin-x86_64/aarch64-linux-android/bin/` this is the path where nkd-build is trying to find `ld` executable. I didn't find `ld` itself in this directory but there were `ld.bfd` and `ld.gold` executables (as I believe they are specific to linux platform). So I just created a symlink `ld ~> ld.gold` and after that build completed successfully.